# Centering borderless buttons between a horizontal line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

I am trying my attempt at borders buttons in android. Currently I have an activity where the buttons look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The buttons are separated by a vertical line and I would like them centered in their "columns" which are created by the vertical lines:

Here is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

            <!-- Card Contents go here -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/breweryTitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle = "bold"
                android:padding="5dip"
                >
            </TextView>




        </LinearLayout >

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

            <!-- Card Contents go here -->


            <ImageView android:id="@+id/breweryImage"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"/>


        </LinearLayout >

    </FrameLayout>





<TableLayout  

android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:shrinkColumns="*"  
android:stretchColumns="*">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

            <!-- Card Contents go here -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/breweryEstablished"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="Year Established: "
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle = "bold"
                android:padding="5dip"
                >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/yearTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:padding="5dip"
                >
            </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout >

    </FrameLayout>





</TableLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

            <!-- Card Contents go here -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/beerDescriptionTitle2"
                android:textStyle = "bold"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Description:"
                android:padding="5dip"
                ></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/breweryDescription"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:padding="5dip"

                ></TextView>





        </LinearLayout >

    </FrameLayout>



    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/discoverLabel"
                android:textStyle = "bold"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Discover:"
                android:padding="5dip"
                ></TextView>

            <!-- Card Contents go here -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="All Beers"
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:onClick="getAllBeers"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Top Beers"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:onClick="getTopBeers"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Your Beers"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:onClick="getYourTopBeers"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Directions to Brewery"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:onClick="getDirections"
                />





        </LinearLayout >

    </FrameLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried playing with the layout width and gravity but still no luck.

Update:

I tried the recent suggestions and I now have them all centered correctly but it just makes everything super long and I can not see the third last button.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/discoverLabel"
                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Discover:"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    ></TextView>

                <!-- Card Contents go here -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >


                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="All Beers"
                        android:id="@+id/button"
                        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                        android:textColor="@color/orange"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:onClick="getAllBeers"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_weight="0.33"/>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
                        android:layout_width="1dip"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Top Beers"
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                        android:textColor="@color/orange"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:onClick="getTopBeers"
                        android:layout_weight="0.33"
                        />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
                        android:layout_width="1dip"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Your Beers"
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                        android:textColor="@color/orange"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:onClick="getYourTopBeers"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_weight="0.33"
                        />


                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Directions to Brewery"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:onClick="getDirections"
                    />



            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>
```

[image]

I also tried changing the linear layout its in to wrap-content for height but that didnt fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using center_horizontal instead of center for gravity value. Also weight is meant to be a float, and since you want about 1/3rd the width for each you should use 0.33 instead of 1. You can only make use of layout_weight horizontally if you set layout_width="0", so do that too! And as moveaway00 said, you should make sure the parent layout is using match_parent not wrap_content.

Summary: there's a bunch of mistakes, use the background colour trick I mention in comments below to methodically debug such issues in future ;)

Comment: That kind of jus moved the text up for some reason.

Comment: try checking the actual size of each Button by setting their backgrounds to different, obvious colours. Also, does the problem exist without those 1dp wide Views in the layout?

Comment: I have what I want working on another activity, I put a screenshot of the working one along with the xml code.  I can not figure out why this one is different.

Comment: I have a hunch that the 3 buttons are each the size of the text (wrapping) rather than 1/3rd of the screen width, you can check that by setting the backgrounds to, say, green.

Comment: that almost fixed it. It got the buttons lined up correctly, but now the page is super long. I pasted my changed xml, and screenshot and what i tried to fix this issue.

Comment: I accidently put 0dp for width for my third 4th button which is not part of the three spaced out ones. Fixed my height issue!

Answer (score 2):

The linear layout that wraps the buttons should have a `layout_width` of `match_parent`, not `wrap content`. This way, it will take all space available.

What we have is basically illustrated below: `layout_weight` distributes the **extra** space of the layout to the children based on the number provided. Since width is told to wrap its children, there is no extra space. If we give a larger size, like `match_parent`, there will be extra space, and so that extra space will be given to the children based on the number given to `layout_weight`. In this case, it will give equal amounts to each button, so they will be the same size.

[image: Demonstration]